# Python - how to convert a 24-bit PNG image to 32-bit using Open-cv or PIL

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a 24-bit PNG image to 32-bit so that it can be displayed on the LED matrix. Here is the code which I have used, but it converted 24-bit to 48-bit

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
i = cv2.imread("bbb.png")
img = np.array(i, dtype = np.uint16)
img *= 256
cv2.imwrite('test.png', img)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the LED matrix you're speaking about. The conversion will mostly depend on the 32bits representation that this hardware expects as input.

Comment: LED matrix is a 32X18 RGB leds matrix, everything is already setup, I am stuck at converting the image to a compatible so that it can work

Comment: If we can somehow convert the image from 24-bit to 32-bit, then it can be shown on Led matrix

Comment: To clarify, do you have an array of LEDs that is 32 wide by 18 tall?

Comment: I am a bit doubtful that the above code converts from 24-bit to 48-bit. Anyway, you would probably need an appropriate container. Have you tried just changing dtype to `dtype=np.uint32`? The `256` constant should be OK, if the input is 24-bit.

Comment: @norok2 3-channel images of 8-bits per code value are commonly referred to as 24-bit color. It's less common to refer to a 3-channel image of 16-bits per code value as a 48-bit image. I think the OP wants 10-12 bits per code value packed into a 16 bit container, but it's unclear.

Comment: Right, right. Then the problem may be the constant.. should multiply by `2 ** 2` or `2 ** 4` per channel instead of `2 ** 8` per channel. But then I am puzzled by the `32-bit` representation, not divisible by 3. Perhaps all he needs to do is to add an `alpha` channel?

Comment: What make/model is this LED matrix please? 32-bit data normally means 8 bits each of RGBA, and it seems unlikely that an LED would display an alpha channel. Or 32-bits means CMYK which is also pretty unlikely for an LED. Please also share your image.

Comment: @NateTheGrate yes it is an array of 32 width and 18 height

Comment: After trying dtype = np.uint32 I have got this error "cv2.imwrite('test.png', img)
TypeError: img data type = 8 is not supported"

Comment: I have used this script for LED matrix: http://aoakley.com/articles/2015-11-18-raspberry-pi-christmas-led-matrix.php

Comment: I don't see any reference to a 32bit color depth requirement for this hardware. I looked [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/software) and [here](http://aoakley.com/articles/ledmatrix.py.php). Their code uses a Color class that takes 3 channels with value ranging from 0 to 255, so 24bits.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the `christmas.png` image in the code you linked to, and it appears to be a 624x8 pixel image with a palette and an 8-bit alpha channel.

Assuming the sample image works, you can make one with the same characteristics by taking a PNG image and adding a fully opaque alpha channel like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image

# Load the image and convert to 32-bit RGBA
im = Image.open("image.png").convert('RGBA')

# Save result
im.save("result.png")
```

I generated a gradient image and applied that processing and got this, so maybe you can try that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have confused the color bit-depth with the size of the input image/array.  From the links posted in the comments, there is no mention of 32 as a bit depth. The script at that tutorial link uses an image with 3-channel, 8-bit color (red, green, and blue code values each represented as numbers from 0-255). The input image must have the same height  as the array, but can be a different width to allow scrolling.

For more on bit-depth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: Actually, I have tried christmas.png and it worked but I have converted another picture into any width but 18 height just like christmas.png but it didn't work

Comment: Then I have checked its details and one thing I have got is that both pics had different bit depths, so I thought, may be it can be solved if pics have bit depth like the working pic

Comment: Oops! I had the wrong answer then. Mark Setchell's answer will probably work for you then. You should edit those details / your debugging steps / the specific error into the question, for future reference.