# How to change image bit-depth? What other package replace the deprecated function imageop.grey2grey4?

Tags: python, image, bit-depth

I am trying to change image bit-depth from 8-bit -> 4-bit, 8-bit -> 2-bit, etc, using python. I found an imageop function called imageop.grey2gray4 that implemented it converting an 8-bit greyscale image to a 4-bit greyscale image without dithering, but sadly it was deprecated. Do you know what other package implemented it?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295414/python-how-to-convert-a-24-bit-png-image-to-32-bit-using-open-cv-or-pil/52300123  ?

Comment: Hi @Ahmet Tavli, your suggestion it is not what i need, because PIL has a convert function, but it just has few modes like 1 (B&W), L (monochrome), but not for specific bit-depths like 4-bit, 5-bit, etc.